# get Thumbnail image from wikimedia commons

Tags: thumbnails, wikipedia-api

I do have a filename from wikimedia commons and I want to access the thumbnail-image directly.

**Example:** Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg

I found a way to get json-data containing the url to the thumbnail I want:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=200
```

but I don't want another request. Is there a way to access the thumbnail directly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're okay to rely on the fact the current way of building the URL won't change in the future (which is not guaranteed), then you can do it.

The URL looks like this:

`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg/200px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg`

- The first part is always the same: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb`
- The second part is the first character of the MD5 hash of the file name. In this case, the MD5 hash of `Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg` is `a85d416ee427dfaee44b9248229a9cdd`, so we get `/a`.
- The third part is the first two characters of the MD5 hash from above: `/a8`.
- The fourth part is the file name: `/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg`
- The last part is the desired thumbnail width, and the file name again: `/200px-Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg`

Comment: I love it! Thank you!

Comment: @svick thanks for the answer - it got me a long way. On thing though: the md5 hash is calculated after replacing all spaces in the filename with underscores

Comment: Just learned that if the image is a .svg you need to add .png to make it work. E.g.: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Ei-map.svg/440px-Ei-map.svg.png

Answer (score 4):

Solution in Python based on the solution of @svick:

```
import hashlib
def get_wc_thumb(image, width=300): # image = e.g. from Wikidata, width in pixels
    image = image.replace(' ', '_') # need to replace spaces with underline 
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(image.encode('utf-8'))
    d = m.hexdigest()
    return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/"+d[0]+'/'+d[0:2]+'/'+image+'/'+str(width)+'px-'+image
```

Comment: For image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E3%82%B8%E3%83%96%E3%83%81%E5%A4%A7%E4%BD%BF%E9%A4%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%80%E8%BB%92%E5%AE%B6.jpg I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)` at `m.update(image.encode('utf-8'))`.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is doing this query in SPARQL instead of Python:
There exists an MD5 function in SPARQL and the whole string manipulation can be implemented in SPARQL too!

```
  BIND(REPLACE(wikibase:decodeUri(STR(?image)), "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/", "") as ?fileName) .
  BIND(REPLACE(?fileName, " ", "_") as ?safeFileName)
  BIND(MD5(?safeFileName) as ?fileNameMD5) .
  BIND(CONCAT("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/", SUBSTR(?fileNameMD5, 1, 1), "/", SUBSTR(?fileNameMD5, 1, 2), "/", ?safeFileName, "/650px-", ?safeFileName) as ?thumb)
```

Run this live query in Wikidata's query service: [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fthumb%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fident%20wdt%3AP31%7Cwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ1075%20.%0A%20%20%3Fident%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%09%09%0A%20%20%3Fident%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20.%0A%0A%20%20BIND%28REPLACE%28wikibase%3AdecodeUri%28STR%28%3Fimage%29%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSpecial%3AFilePath%2F%22%2C%20%22%22%29%20as%20%3FfileName%29%20.%0A%20%20BIND%28REPLACE%28%3FfileName%2C%20%22%20%22%2C%20%22_%22%29%20as%20%3FsafeFileName%29%0A%20%20BIND%28MD5%28%3FsafeFileName%29%20as%20%3FfileNameMD5%29%20.%0A%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28%22https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F%22%2C%20SUBSTR%28%3FfileNameMD5%2C%201%2C%201%29%2C%20%22%2F%22%2C%20SUBSTR%28%3FfileNameMD5%2C%201%2C%202%29%2C%20%22%2F%22%2C%20%3FsafeFileName%2C%20%22%2F650px-%22%2C%20%3FsafeFileName%29%20as%20%3Fthumb%29%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%3D%22fr%22%29%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2012), as discussed here: https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org/t/accessing-a-commons-thumbnail-via-wikidata/499

Comment: To have scalable vector graphics (SVG) also work out—and just improving on the given answer—append  `…svg.png` to the `?safeFileName` like so `REPLACE(?safeFileName, "^(.+[Ss][Vv][Gg])$", "$1.png")`